# Add second onmouseover action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following script:

```
<?php
$main_image  = get_field('main_image');
$hover_image  = get_field('hover_image');
$button_text  = get_field('button_text');
?>


<img src="<?php echo $main_image; ?>"
onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo $hover_image; ?>'" 
onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $main_image; ?>'" />
```

How can I display `<?php echo $button_text; ?>` on mouseover also?

Thanks!

Comment: Any ideas, mates?

Comment: use Javascript's addEventListener method instead of putting inline event handlers on your HTML. Then you can add as many handlers for the same event as you like. Lots of documentation of that online, and tutorials, just search around.

Comment: Or, just make your onmouseover execute a function which can carry out multiple commands to do all the things you want.

Comment: Sorry, but my js knowledge is not so reach. SO I simply don't know how to do that in such a way ;(

Answer (score 1):

You can use title attribute of img tag to show $button_text value whenever mouseover event run.
e.g.

```
<img src="<?php echo $main_image; ?>" title=""
onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo $hover_image; ?>'" 
onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $main_image; ?>'" />
```

And if you want to show button text in different way then also let me know how you want to show? so i can help you for that also.

Comment: Thanks mate! Unfortunately I think that title is not I'm looking for. I just wanted to swap image on mouseover and display the button with this text (as overlay). Don't you know how to do it in such a way?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Opacity with Box</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">John Doe</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have provided one example which is related to your requirements, please check with this example and let me know if still you have any concern.